# Imperfective Aspect in German "not since" constructions

Tags: tense, time

I was recently forced to confess, in German, that I haven't spoken in a while:

> Ich habe seit sechs Jahren kein Deutsch gesprochen

Immediately I realized this was wrong, and felt inclined to say:

> Ich spreche seit sechs Jahren kein Deutsch

But that feels like a description of capacity or volition rather than habit. I am struggling to imagine the German way to form this imperfective sense of "the last time I spoke German regularly was six years ago" without fundamentally changing the content of the sentence. I have similar trouble imagining the same construction in other sentences where "not since" phrases are included, for example:

> Ich gehe seit Januar nicht mehr täglich joggen

Comment: Wieso denkst Du, der erste Satz sei falsch? Und haben die Sternchen vor den Sätzen was zu bedeuten?

Comment: @userunknown Vor allem, "falsch" im Sinne von "So wuerde diese Gedanke von einem Deutschen nicht ausgedrueckt." Die Sternchen zeigen, dass ein Beispiel irgendwie ungueltig ist.

Comment: *I was recently forced to confess* - Thumbscrews? ;)

Answer (score 8):

Actually, your first example

> Ich habe schon seit sechs Jahren kein Deutsch [mehr] gesprochen

was not wrong, but instead nearly perfectly idiomatic, even more if you had added the optional particle "mehr".

Native speakers would probably express the same thing rather with a duration rather than a point in time (which might explain your problems):

> Ich hatte die letzten 5 Jahre keine Gelegenheit, Deutsch zu sprechen

Whereas

> Ich spreche schon seit 5 Jahren kein Deutsch [mehr]

would somewhat imply a deliberate decision 5 years ago to stop speaking German like in

> Ich rauche schon seit 5 Jahren nicht mehr

Comment: What is the function of `schon` in your examples?

Comment: "schon" emphasizes the length of the time period, comparable to "I haven't spoken German for six years _already_".

Comment: Particles like *schon* are the fine adjustment screws of  German sentences.

Comment: Wenn Du vor 6 Jahren auf einer Insel gestrandet wärst wie Robinson, und aus Mangel an Gelegenheit nicht mehr geraucht hättest, könntest Du auch sagen "Ich rauche schon seit 5 Jahren nicht mehr". M.a.W.: Die Aussage mit der bewussten Entscheidung halte ich für substanzlos.Vgl. "Ich warte schon seit 2 Stunden".

Comment: @userunknown In diesem speziellen Beispiel halte ich die bewußte Entscheidung für wesentlich wahrscheinlicher als "auf der Insel stranden". Aber ich gebe dir (ein bißchen) recht.

Comment: The difference is miniscule and thus not grammatical, because the decision to break the spell by speaking german would have to be deliberate in some sense, and so it may be assumed that not speaking was deliberate just as much. Which may be not much at all, but not not anything either. The claim that *seit* confers a perspective that were different to *fünf Jahre lang* would have to be substantiated. It does not relate to *sein*, ie. subjunctive mood and a weird inflection to say "It be 5 years before I speak German again", "Ich habe seins 5 Jahre ...", is it? Sounds rather like an estimate.

Comment: Ohne die nötigen alt-deutschen Zwischenschritte zu betrachten, legt die Wurzel  [\*sithus](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/sīþuz) "late" zumindest einen eigentlichen Sinn des wartens nahe, der so oder so passt; Vergleich auch "fünf lange Jahre", demnach ebenso ein Sinn En. *longing* unterstellt werden kann.